# Prestashop convertPrice doesn't convert price

Tags: prestashop-1.6

Using Prestashop 1.6.1.4

The theme function

```
{convertPrice price=$total}
```

Add the current currency sign but doesn't actually convert the to the chosen currency.

I followed the debugger to function (classes/Product.php, line 3034):

```
public static function convertPrice($params, &$smarty)
    {
        return Tools::displayPrice($params['price'], Context::getContext()->currency);
    }
```

Which is strange since the convertPrice eventually calls displayPrice while `Tools::convertPrice(...)` is the function that convert the currency (but doesn't add the currency sign).

So I change it to :

```
        return Tools::displayConvertPrice($params['price'], Context::getContext()->currency);
```

and added to Tools.php

```
public function displayConvertPrice($price, $currency)
{
    return Tools::displayPrice(Tools::convertPrice($price, $currency), $currency);
}
```

My question:
Is it a bug or that I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Who knows what the devs wanted with that but there is a smarty function

```
{convertAndFormatPrice price=$total}
```

which does what you want.

You can open `/config/smarty.config.inc.php` and you'll see all prestashop functions registered in smarty `smartyRegisterFunction(yada yada)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
{toolsConvertPrice price=$total}
```

this works for me on PS 1.6.1.12.